# Is there a way to create array with custom values using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays

Hello i want to ask is there a way to create an `array`  with custom values without using loop and assign the values for example i want to create `array with [2,1]`  shape and i want to fill the first column with value of `(-1)`  and the second with value of `(2)`  i have read the numpy docs "https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-creation.html" but i didn't find this functionality. Thank you for any help.

```py
theta = np.array([1, 2])  <-- how to assign diff values per column ?
theta.fill(-1)
```

I want to obtain the following result

```
   array([[-1, 2],
       [-1, 2]
       [-1, 2]
       [-1, 2]])
```

Comment: Can you write down the result that you want to obtain?

Comment: You mean something like `theta[...] = [-1, 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the syntax of a full loop you can do the following.

For a simple array you can do this:

```
array = [[-1,2] for _ in range(3)]
```

Otherwise, for a numpy array, (documentation here [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.creation.html)) you can simply ass np.array (as follows):

```
array = np.array([[-1,2] for _ in range(3)])
```

Comment: Thank you all. @spassador this was exactly that i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.zeros(shape=(4,2), dtype=int)
theta[:,0] = -1
theta[:,1] = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use indexing:

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.zeros((4,2))
theta[:, [0,1]] = [-1,2]
```

Or `ellipsis`:

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.zeros((4,2))
theta[...] = [-1,2]
```

Both result in:

```
array([[-1.,  2.],
       [-1.,  2.],
       [-1.,  2.],
       [-1.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

```
np.array([-1, 2] * 4).reshape(4,2)
```

Comment: Thank you this is easy editable i have tried different dimensions they work fine

Comment: It is my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function in numpy to achieve this.

In your case, following single line of code would do the job without using any loop or even list comprehenssion

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.full((4,2), fill_value=(-1,2))
Out[2]: 
array([[-1,  2],
       [-1,  2],
       [-1,  2],
       [-1,  2]])
```

Refer to the numpy doc for more details [numpy.full](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html). Enjoy!